# How to run tests on PR, deploy on merge with Travis CI

Tags: github, travis-ci

I'm automating the testing and deployment of a web app. I have the following stages that need to run:

1. Test
2. Deploy (dev)
3. Deploy (prod)

When a PR is opened, I'd like only stages *1. (test)* and *2. (deploy, dev)* to run. Then, when the PR is merged to master, I'd like only stage *3. (deploy, prod)* to run. I don't want any CI/CD on regular commits/pushes.

Here's how I'm trying to define my `.travis.yml`:

```
# install and other things omitted for brevity
stages:
  - name: dev-test
    if: type = pull_request
    branch:
      except: master
  - name: dev-deploy
    if: type = pull_request
    branch:
      except: master
  - name: prod-deploy
    if: type = pull_request
    branch:
      only: master
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: dev-test
      script: python scripts/dev_test.py
    - stage: dev-deploy
      script: python scripts/dev_deploy.py
    - stage: prod-deploy
      script: python scripts/prod_deploy.py
```

Right now all three stages run when a PR is opened (not just `dev-test` and `dev-deploy`). How should I set up my stages to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by not using build stages altogether. Instead, I just verify attributes of the GitHub PR in my `script` directive in `.travis.yml`, via [Travis environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables).

```
# install and other things omitted for brevity
script:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE == "pull_request" ]] ; then python scripts/dev_test.py ; fi
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE == "pull_request" && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH != "master" ]] ; then python scripts/dev_deploy.py ; fi
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE == "push" && $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]] ; then python scripts/prod_deploy.py ; fi
```